# hiding elements when resizing screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 identical `<div>`s:

```
<div class="box">Hello World!</div>    
<div class="box">Hello World!</div>    
<div class="box">Hello World!</div>
```

I want all of them to be displayed on desktop screen size, only two to be displayed if tablet, only one if mobile. How can I do this using bootstrap and CSS only? (please note I cannot change the html part)

Comment: you can use `nth-of-type` to target the two of them that you want for tablet and one of them for mobile. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: Reading [DOC (Display property)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) before working on any library is a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In **CSS**, we can use Media Queries.

   ```
   @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .box:first-of-type,
    .box:last-of-type {
     display: none;
    }
   }

   @media (max-width: 992px) {
     .box:first-of-type {
      display: none;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Bootstrap comes with **Utility Classes**. We use them directly in the HTML. To achieve the same result using utitlity classes, we can do.

   ```
   <div class="box d-none d-md-block">Hello World!</div>
   <div class="box d-none d-lg-block">Hello World!</div>
   <div class="box">Hello World!</div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media query for this. And with CSS you can select element by it's position. So basically @imran's answer  will work to your concern.

Media Query Detecting your window size and it triggering CSS part when it comes to that size of screen. Then `.box:last-child` , `.box:first-child` selectors will select the your n'th element in the html. For more details please follow the following links.

- Media Query: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
- nTh Selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp

Comment: Hey There. min-width:768px repeated twice in your code. :) Correct this Mate

Comment: Thank you mate, i just copied your code. Thank you man!

Answer (score 0):

I can show you the easy way to to this:

In HTML file you change to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<div class="box desktop tablet mobile">Hello World!</div>
<div class="box desktop tablet">Hello World!</div>
<div class="box desktop">Hello World!</div>
```

In your CSS you just do this:

```
.box {
    display: none;
}    

@media only screen and (min-width: 1150px) {    
    .box.tablet {
        display: none;
    }    
    .box.desktop {
        display: block;
    }    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1149px) {    
    .box.desktop {
        display: none;
    }    
    .box.tablet {
        display: block;
    }        
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {    
    .box.desktop {
        display: none;
    }    
    .box.tablet {
        display: none;
    }    
    .box.mobile {
        display: block;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query in css to do determine the type of device of device and use the **nth-of-child** to hide the elements using `display:none`. The code snippet given below explaind it better.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .box:first-child, .box:last-child{
        display:none
        }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .box:first-child{
        display:none
        }
```

576px is used for Mobile and 768px for Tablets and all the three divs will be visible by default in desktop devices.